# mysql query to join five tables

Tags: mysql, sql

want to join tables

i have five tables like this

**Table-1** named as **software**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `software` (
  `software_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `software_version` varchar(10) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `software` (`software_name`, `software_version`) VALUES
('freemap', '1.0'),
('freegps', '1.2');
```

[image]

**Table-2** named as **cms**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cms` (
  `cms_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `cms_product` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `cms_version` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `cms` (`cms_name`, `cms_product`, `cms_version`) VALUES
('org:freemap:1.0', 'freemap', '1.0'),
('org:freegps:1.0', 'freegps', '1.2');
```

[image]

**Table-3** named as **cms_to_sve**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cms_to_sve` (
  `cms_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `sw_vul_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `cms_to_sve` (`cms_id`, `sw_vul_id`) VALUES
('org:freemap:1.0', '423'),
('org:freemap:1.0', '424'),
('org:freemap:1.0', '425'),
('org:freemap:1.0', '426'),
('org:freegps:1.2', '940'),
('org:freegps:1.2', '941');
```

[image]

**Table-4** named as **software_details**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `software_details` (
  `sw_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `sve_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `score` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `ratio` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `swe_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `software_details` (`sw_id`, `sve_id`, `score`, `ratio`, `swe_id`) VALUES
('423', '2001-1991', '5', 'high', '320'),
('424', '2004-1996', '7.5', 'medium', '460'),
('425', '2008-9001', '8', 'low', '122'),
('426', '2012-0002', '4', 'high', '128'),
('940', '2003-1993', '6', 'medium', '424'),
('941', '2006-1994', '3', 'high', '112');
```

[image]

**Table-5** named as **swe**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `swe` (
  `swe_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `swe_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `swe_des` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `swe` (`swe_name`, `swe_id`, `swe_des`) VALUES
('ref software', '320', 'hello'),
('ref complicated', '480', 'hi welcome'),
('ref contact', '122', 'how are you'),
('ref admire', '123', 'who is that'),
('ref super', '424', 'well join us'),
('ref nice', '112', 'cheers');
```

[image]

i want to join these five tables

i have few hints

- need to compare **table 1** and **table 2** (that is table
  **software** and table **cms**)
- compare **software_name** with **cms_product** and
  **software_version** with **cms_version**
- these should relate with cms_name
- with second table column **cms_name** has to join with the third
  table  common column **cms_id**
- where in third table **cms_id** must be equal to **sw_vul_id**
  then join fourth table
- now join fourth table from third table using **sw_vul_id** is equal
  to **sw_id** and get the remaining column values
- join fifth table and fourth table by **swe-id** and get the other
  column values

finally i want to have an output like this

[image]

i need query for this .

Comment: "LEFT JOIN" is your friend...

Comment: iam not able to query it , just i have an idea how to relate tables ,iam new to this can you help me with the query

Comment: Perhaps you should start by writing a query to query just the first two tables, and get the columns from those tables output as you desire, then add in the third table to get some more data and gradually build up what you want to achieve. If you then get stuck, you'll have a question to bring to Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow isn't here to do your work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like PeteCon said in his comment , left join can be used, hope this will help.

```
   select tbl1.software_name, tbl1.software_version, tbl4.sve_id, tbl4.score, tbl4.ratio, tbl5.swe_id, tbl5.swe_name, tbl5.swe_des
     from software tbl1
left join cms tbl2 on tbl1.software_name = tbl2.cms_product and tbl1.software_version = tbl2.cms_version
left join cms_to_sve tbl3 on tbl2.cms_name = tbl3.cms_id
left join software_details tbl4 on tbl3.sw_vul_id = tbl4.sw_id
left join swe tbl5 on tbl4.swe_id = tbl5.swe_id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3735e7/1

I think some of your sample data is not sufficient to get the result that you want, but in your real database the query should give you something like you want.